# change the label color if checkbox is checked and red if checkbox is unchecked

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to create a custom checkbox since its hard to style the native html checkbox so below is what I have tried. The checkbox is checked and unchecked when I click the label but I cant change the border color of the label when the input checkbox is checked and unchecked. Any help, ideas, suggestions, recommendations is greatly appreciated.

```css
input[type="checkbox"]{display:none;}
label{
  border:1px solid red;
  width: 15px;
  height:15px;
  display:block;
}
label + input:checked{
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do what you want with that hierarchy (without JavaScript) as there is no parent selector. You'd need to move the label after the checkbox and then use the adjacent sibling combinator `+`:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: block;
}

input:checked + label{
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="cb" type="checkbox">
  <label for="cb"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: I see, I don't want to use id's on the checkbox to bind with the label as I intend to create multiple checkboxes and creating each checkbox a unique id is a pain in the head. Is there a way to not use id on the checkbox with the label?

Comment: Not to do what you want since the only other option, when using a label, is to wrap the input element with it (as you did originally), and then you're back to the problem of not having a parent selector to use. If you want to use a label with an input, and not wrap it, you have to use IDs.